# How to go from one page to another

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a SignIn form and I want to create the SignUp link.

On link click I want to open SignUp page.

I have created index.js nothing in that another app.js I wrote SignIn logic.

```
Here is the Code :

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {   
       super(props);
       this.state = {
          email: "",
          password: ""
       };
     }

     validateForm() {  
         return this.state.email.length > 0 && this.state.password.length > 0;
      }

      handleChange = event => {
           this.setState({
             [event.target.id]: event.target.value
            });
       }

      handleSubmit = event => {
         event.preventDefault();
      }

      render(){
          return (  

            <div class="container">

             <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>

                 <div id="login">

                <div class="form-group">

                <h2 align="center">Login Form</h2>

                 Email :

                 <input type="email" id="email" value={this.state.email} onChange={this.handleChange} class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address"/><br/>

                  Password :
                  <input type="password" id="password" value={this.state.password} onChange={this.handleChange} class="form-control" placeholder="Password"/><br/>

                  <a href= " Signup / ">Sign Up</a><br/><br/>//here I want to change 

                  <button id="send" disabled={!this.validateForm()} class="btn btn-default">Sign In</button>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </form>
                            </div>
                    );
                  }
                }

                export default App;
```

I have added the Anchor tag in that but it won't work . I want to create the link in place of anchor tag in that onclick the signup page will open. I have started to create signUp page also

here is my code:

```
                import React, { Component } from 'react';
                import './App.css';
            export default class Signup extends Component {

                  render(){
                            return (

                            <div class ="container">

                              <form>           

                                  <div id="signup">

                                  <div class="form-group">

                                  First Name :
                                    <input type="text" id="first" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name"/><br/>

                                  Last Name :
                                    <input type="text" id="last" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name"/><br/>

                                  Email :
                                    <input type="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email"/><br/>

                                  Password :  

                                    <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password"/><br/>

                                  Re-enter Password :

                                    <input type="password" id="confirm" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Password"/><br/>

                                    <button id="save">Save</button>

                                </div>
                                </div>
                                </form>
                                </div>
                    );
                  }
                }
```

How do I create the routes to go from one page to another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Link` instead of `a` tag:

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
.
.
<Link to='/signup'>Sign Up</Link>
```

EDIT: I'm updating the code for your solution for now, but I need you to understand you might not be getting such a solution whenever you post questions here. Stack Overflow requires you to read through any documentation and do extensive research before asking any question.
I need you to look at the code below and fully understand it by reading the React Router docs before copy-pasting it.

Change your `App.js` to:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Signup from './Signup';
import './App.css';

class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      email: "",
      password: ""
    };
  }

  validateForm() {
    return this.state.email.length > 0 && this.state.password.length > 0;
  }

  handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.id]: event.target.value
    });
  }

  handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div class ="container">
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <div id="login">
            <div class="form-group">
              <h2 align="center">Login Form</h2>
              Email :
                <input type="email" id="email" value={this.state.email} onChange={this.handleChange} class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address"/><br/>
              Password :
                <input type="password" id="password" value={this.state.password} onChange={this.handleChange} class="form-control" placeholder="Password"/><br/>
                <Link to="/signup">Signup</Link>
                <button id="send" disabled={!this.validateForm()} class="btn btn-default">Sign In</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
            <Router>
              <Switch>
                <Route exact path='/' component={Login}/>
                <Route path='/signup' component={Signup}/>
              </Switch>
            </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

and your expected working is achieved. Let me know if that solved by accepting this answer, or comment below.
P.S: React Router docs: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/philosophy
Happy Coding!

Comment: Perfect answer . Thank You, So much Sir.

Comment: ...and stop calling anybody _sir_ :) we're all peers here!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using react-router 4.x and above, then import it like this

```
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
```

For react-router versions < 4.x

```
import {Link} from 'react-router';
```

And in your return, you can link to another page by

```
<Link to="/signup">Signup</Link>
```

Comment: I got error 'react-router' does not contain an export named 'Link'.

Comment: which version of react-router are you using?

Comment: "react-router": "^4.2.0",

Comment: updated the original answer to support react-router 4.x

Comment: what is the answer

Comment: import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'; Check the answer above :)

Comment: got list of errors :TypeError: _this.props.history is undefined
Router
node_modules/react-router/es/Router.js:31

  28 |   }
  29 | 
  30 |   return _ret = (_temp = (_this = _possibleConstructorReturn(this, _React$Component.call.apply(_React$Component, [this].concat(args))), _this), _this.state = {
> 31 |     match: _this.computeMatch(_this.props.history.location.pathname)
  32 |   }, _temp), _possibleConstructorReturn(_this, _ret);
  33 | }
  34 |

Comment: constructClassInstance
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:9760

  9757 | var unmaskedContext = getUnmaskedContext$2(workInProgress);
  9758 | var needsContext = isContextConsumer$1(workInProgress);
  9759 | var context = needsContext ? getMaskedContext$2(workInProgress, unmaskedContext) : emptyObject;
> 9760 | var instance = new ctor(props, context);
  9761 | adoptClassInstance(workInProgress, instance);
  9762 | 
  9763 | // Cache unmasked context so we can avoid recreating masked context unless necessary.

Comment: updateClassComponent
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:10215

  10212 | if (current === null) {
  10213 |   if (!workInProgress.stateNode) {
  10214 |     // In the initial pass we might need to construct the instance.
> 10215 |     constructClassInstance(workInProgress, workInProgress.pendingProps);
  10216 |     mountClassInstance(workInProgress, priorityLevel);
  10217 |     shouldUpdate = true;
  10218 |   } else {

Comment: Can you update the question with your routes part of the code?

Comment: sir plz wait I will send my git hub link

Comment: From your github code, i could not find routes being written anywhere! Are you sure if you have written the routes?

Comment: I m new plz check once my git repository